Can SO_RCVTIMEO be used for two recvfrom() calls
I have set up a receive timeout like this:
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = timeout;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
if (setsockopt(sock_temp, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof(tv)) < 0) {
    perror("Setting socket timeout failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

While I have two loops in this function that call recvfrom to get two different types of UDP packets, in this case, the second recvfrom seems to reach the timeout threshold immediately after entering that loop. My hypothesis is the timeout for sockfd should be re-set once being reached.
The loop looks basically like this:
for (int i = 0; i < packet_num; i++) {
    int n = (int) recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, packet_size, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN) {
            printf("Receive timeout\n");
            break;
    }
}

I thought about using a new struct timeval new_tv and re-setting the timeout for sockfd using the new one, but it does not seem to work.

SO_RCVTIMEO is a socket property. The timeout starts not when setting it, but with each call of recvfrom. So it does not need to set again for each recvfrom again, which explains why "it does not seem to work". There is likely a different issue here, only the provided code which just "looks basically like this" is not sufficient to explain it. You need to provide (minimal) code where it actually happens so one can help.

It isn't valid to check errno unless the immediately prior system call returned -1. You aren't getting a timeout on the second recvmsg() at all: you are getting a datagram.

Alternatively, you can use select() or (e)poll() or equivalent to handle the per-read timeout instead of SO_RCVTIMEO
